# knockoutjs - Multiple dropdowns with same selectedOptions/value observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, drop-down-menu, ko.observablearray

I have a knockout foreach binding that generates multiple dropdowns, both single select and multi select. I don't know upfront how much dropdowns there are going to be.

All dropdowns are populated of items of the same datatype but filtered, however I want to gather all selected items from all dropdowns in one observableArray. Binding the same observableArray to all dropdowns in the foreach loop doesn't work as it gets added to the observableArray and immediately deleted by the other dropdown(s).

```
<script id="multiselect" type="text/html">
    <select class="multi-select" multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: Items, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Guid', selectedOptions: $root.selectedItems"></select>
</script>
<script id="singleselect" type="text/html">
    <select class="single-select" data-bind="options: Items, value: $root.selectedItems"></select>
</script>

<div class="separator">
    <!-- ko foreach: distinctItemTypes -->
    <label data-bind="text: ItemType.Name"></label>
    <div>
        <!-- ko template: { name: Count > 1 ? 'multiselect' : 'singleselect' } --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Is this possible or what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have each `select` bind to a different `observableArray` for its selected values contained within the item you're currently looping over, then add a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) at the root level to bring them all together:

```
var distinctItemType = function() {
  this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray();
}

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.distinctItemTypes = ko.observableArray();

  this.allSelectedOptions = ko.computed(function() {
    var ret = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < self.distinctItemTypes().length; x++)
      ret = ret.concat(self.distinctItemTypes()[x].selectedOptions());

    return ret;
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, except this would only work when the number of dropdowns is static. For me its variable there can be 1, 2, 5 or more dropdowns.

Comment: Do you have a way of individually changing what each `select` is bound to?  Seeing more of your viewmodel may help.

Comment: @Sander Specifically, what `distinctItemTypes` is made up of.  I'm thinking that putting the selected options binding on each item type would be the way to go, then using something similar to what I posted to bring them all together at the root level

Comment: @Sander Have edited the post with what I'm getting at - made some assumptions about what `distinctItemTypes` is.  If this doesn't help, could you add more context to your question please?

Comment: yes I was actually just thinking the same. distinctItemTypes is made up from some properties, one of the is the filtered list. Let's see if I can add an observableArray to all of them and then create a computed to put them together.